# replace text with different pattern

Tags: r, regex

I'm working with a list of text which contains PII information that are masked like XXXX XXXX, this can be phome numbers or address numbers. I want to remove the mask.

```
x <- c('This is my phone number xxx xxx xxx', 'The account number is XXXXXXXXXX', 'Her age is xx', 'The credit number is xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx', 'This is the list of accounts xxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxx')
```

I wrote something like this, but it is not replacing everything:

```
gsub("(?:\\s+|^)\\S*(?<!\\w)(?:xxxx?|xxxxxxxx)(?!\\w)\\S*", "", x, perl=TRUE)
```

How do I improve this code?

expected output:

'This is my phone number', 
'The account number is', 
'Her age is', 
'The credit number is', 
'This is the list of accounts'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
trimws(gsub("x{2,}", "", x, ignore.case = T))
```

or

```
trimws(gsub("(x|X){2,}", "", x))

[1] "This is my phone number"      "The account number is"        "Her age is"                  
[4] "The credit number is"         "This is the list of accounts"
```

Comment: @capiono Thanks for the accept. But, to be honest, my solution does not deserve it. To my mind, you should accept @akrun's solution. Not only was his answer prior to mine, it is is also safer because it makes sure that what you call the mask must occur as a string bounded by white space (cf. `\\b`). My solution also matches, and thus removes, strings such as `xx` occurring **inside** a word. Granted, that scenario is highly unlikely in English (only the brand name `Exxon`comes to mind). But all in all @akrun's solution is smarter.

Comment: @akrun thanks for answering the question, both solution worked great. sorry I didn't select yours. I honestly just accepted the answer at the top. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

If we need to remove the repeating 'x' or ('X'), specify the pattern with word boundary (`\\b`) followed by one or more 'x' (`\\x+`) till the word boundary (`\\b`) and replace it with blank (`""`).  Also, make use of the `ignore.case = TRUE` (which is by default `FALSE`) to match upper case as well

```
trimws(gsub("\\bx+\\b", "", x, ignore.case = TRUE))
#[1] "This is my phone number"   
#[2] "The account number is"     
#[3] "Her age is"       
#[4] "The credit number is"        
#[5] "This is the list of accounts"
```

---

If we use zero or more space before the word boundary, the `trimws` can be removed

```
gsub("\\s*\\bx+\\b\\s*", "", x, ignore.case = TRUE)
```